# How can I get the list of policies from Asp.Net Core Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

I am creating a web application using Asp.Net Core 1.1.1 and its Authorization/Authentication system.

In my **startup.cs** file I have configured the various policies I need:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        servizi.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Insert", policyBuilder => policyBuilder .RequireClaim("AllowInsert"));
            options.AddPolicy("Update", policyBuilder => policyBuilder .RequireClaim("AllowUpdate"));
            options.AddPolicy("Delete", policyBuilder => policyBuilder .RequireClaim("AllowDelete"));
        });
}
```

Then in a controller I have assigned the claims to a role (the Administrator role):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssignClaimstoAdminRole()
    {
        await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator"), new Claim("AllowInsert", "true"));
        await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator"), new Claim("AllowUpdate", "true"));
        await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator"), new Claim("AllowDelete", "true"));

        await _loginManager.RefreshSignInAsync(await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name));
        return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "MyController");
    }
```

and finally I have protected my views injecting the Authorization Service:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "Insert"))
{
     <i role="submit" class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x"></i>
}
```

**My question is:**
I would like to retrieve the **list** of the policies created in startup.cs, so that eventually I can build a page to add other users/roles assigning them one or more policies already present in the system.

Is there an object which exposes the collection of previously added policies?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Better rely on claims. You always has access to the list of claims.

I'm currently working on this, where application's controllers use policies to grant access, and my menu builder uses claims to add or skip menu item.

I've thought that I can use the same string for claim value and policy name, thus easier to manage.

I've found an interesting article too, about complex filtering, policies and claims: https://andrewlock.net/custom-authorisation-policies-and-requirements-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thank you Barbara. I had read the great article you have suggested, and actually it was the base for my structure, but probably I have not completely understood the concepts behind this authentication schema. I thought that "policies" were at an higher level than "claims", because `AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "Insert")` checks for policies, not for claims. But I am not able to retrieve the list of policies created by `AddPolicy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them from IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.

```
var policies = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
       .SelectMany(actionDescriptor => actionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.SelectMany(filter => (filter.Filter as AuthorizeFilter)?.AuthorizeData?.Select(authData => authData.Policy) ?? new string[0]))
       .Where(policy => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy))
       .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you Benedikt! I have tried to implement your solution but without success.

            `var policies = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
                .SelectMany(actionDescriptor => actionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.SelectMany(filter => (filter.Filter as AuthorizeFilter)?.AuthorizeData?.Select(authData => authData.Policy) ?? new string[0]))
       .Where(policy => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy))
       .Distinct();`

The result is always an empty string even if the policies are present and correctly retrieved. Don't know why!

Comment: I think I found the problem: We have overwritten the AuthorizationPolicyProvider and create the policies on the fly (see https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/creating-dynamic-authorization-policies-aspnet-core/). When you do that, then my code snippet works. But if you define your policies statically (AddPolicy on the AuthorizationOptions), then only the policy requirements are stored, but not the name.

Comment: I dont know if it works, but you could try to write a asp net core mvc convention (see https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/customising-asp-net-mvc-core-behaviour-with-an-iapplicationmodelconvention for an example). Maybe the policy names can be extracted there.